# Inline div is jumping

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have two divs that are placed next to each other ([jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/80ke63nj/)):

```
<div class="container" style="display:block;">
   <div class="topLeft" style="border:1px solid red; display:inline-block;" > <a  runat="server" href="~/">IMAGE<br>
      IMAGE</a> </div>
   <div class="topRight" style="border:1px solid blue; display:inline-block;">
      <div class="topTop" style="display:block;">%</div>
      <div class="topBottom" style="display:block;">#</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

In the example there is no problem, but what I see is that the blue div is placed slightly above the red one (visual example [[jsfiddle link]](https://jsfiddle.net/opj3s46n/)):

```
<div class="container" style="display:block; margin-top:20px;">
   <div class="topLeft" style="border:1px solid red;  display:inline-block;" > <a  runat="server" href="~/">IMAGE<br>
      IMAGE</a> </div>
</div>
<div class="topRight" style="border:1px solid blue; position:absolute; margin-left:60px; margin-top:-50px; display:inline-block;">
   <div class="topTop" style="display:block;">%</div>
   <div class="topBottom" style="display:block;">#</div>
</div>
```

What could be causing this?
(Since it causes so much confusion, the first code is the code I use, the second code is just what I SEE)

Comment: `display:inline-block` doesnt work with `position:abosolute`

Comment: 1. you're DOM is not right as in previous example `container` enclosing both the divs `topLeft` and `topRight` but in your *code* `topRight` is outside of `container`

2. if you want to laid down them side-by-side then why are you using `position: absolute' and such absurd `margin`?

Comment: The second code is just a visual example..the first code is giving me the (approximate) results of the second one. I made the second code to show what I get when using the first.

Comment: @master2080 what is the problem then? Problem is in first code or second? As Vivek and Vitorino mentioned are the problems in second code.

Answer (score 0):

You use second div margin-top:-50px makes the mistakes.

Use the following code:

```
<div class="topRight" style="border:1px solid blue; position:absolute; margin-left:10px;  display:inline-block;float:left">
                    <div class="topTop" style="display:block;">%</div>
                    <div class="topBottom" style="display:block;">#</div>
                </div>
```

Comment: The second code is just a visual example of what i get in the first code.      I made the second code to show what I (approximately) get when using the first.

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix *display* and *position*. It is mostly either/or.

Assuming you want to work using a `display` property, a small tilt can append sometimes (if this is what you're trying to say by using your second example).

If it does, make sure to align your *divs* all together by using the `vertical-align` property.

For example, `vertical-align: top` will horizontally align all *divs* based on their top.

Comment: The second example is just a visual representation of what I see as the result..the first one is the actual code.

Comment: So, what's wrong? You want to get the first or the second? You're not clear.